# No vga output at boot time

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, vga, eee-pc

I have a netbook mobo from an ASUS EEE, (it has 1015px written on it though I'm not sure that was the original model name) taken from a working netbook, I'm connecting it to a VGA display but it has no video output. The board is working, there is HDD activity, leds are blinking, usb keboard leds do respond but theres no output to the monitor. Any ideas? is there a way to make it output to VGA by default at boot time? thanks